# Will Kubuntu 18.04 LTS be supported on 32 bit machines for 5 years?

Tags: 32-bit, 18.04, support

Will Kubuntu 18.04 LTS be supported on 32-bit machines for 5 years?

We downloaded an:

- ISO file for 32-bit installation on i386
- ISO file for 64-bit installation on amd64

Will both platforms be supported for 5 years?

Comment: Generally, Ubuntu LTS is supported for five years. I think Ubuntu-flavor LTS is only supported for three years.

Comment: Is there any reason you actually want to use i386 Kubuntu?  Do you have an Athlon XP or something else so old it can't run amd64?

Comment: At the height of the netbook craze in 2009 or so the N270 and N280 were the dominant netbook chips, neither of them support 64 bit. Until pretty recently I was using one of those machines as my "on the go" system.

Answer (score 10):

This is from [Kubuntu release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#Support_lifespan):

> Support lifespan
>
> Kubuntu 18.04 will be supported for 3 years.

There has never been any difference in the support span before, and the release notes mention none for Kubuntu 18.04. So, for the lack of counter evidence, it is safe to assume that both 32 and 64bit packages will get 3 years of support.

Here is more from [Ubuntu release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Support_lifespan):

> Support lifespan
>
> The 'main' archive of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years until April 2023. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be supported for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, and Ubuntu Core. Ubuntu Studio 18.04 will be supported for 9 months. All other flavors will be supported for 3 years.

PS: There you have it, just read the RNs.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:  No - not for 5 years**

There is a terse statement here:

[Kubuntu 18.04 LTS Support Lifespan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/Kubuntu#Support_lifespan) (wiki.ubuntu.com)

Excerpt:

**Kubuntu 18.04 will be supported for 3 years.**

---

Background:  Here is an article describing 18.04 LTS 32-bit support:

[Ubuntu Is Dropping 32-Bit Images, But the Rest of the Flavors Will Keep Them](https://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-is-dropping-32-bit-images-but-the-rest-of-the-flavors-will-keep-them-517842.shtml)

Excerpt:

**Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and Kubuntu will still offer 32-bit images.**

---

Here is where you can find them:

[Ubuntu 18.04 Flavours Released, Available to Download](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/04/ubuntu-flavors-18-04-release-download-features)  (OMGubuntu.com)

Provides download links for:

- Kubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 LTS,
- Ubuntu Studio 18.04,
- Ubuntu Kylin 18.04 LTS,
- Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS,

---

Comment: Not only Lubuntu, Xubuntu, and Kubuntu will still offer 32-bit images, but also the following community flavours: Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Kylin, Ubuntu Studio and the Ubuntu `mini.iso` alias Netboot. You find them via [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) and [cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/)

Answer (score 0):

gonna put it together:
      *   ubuntu 18.04:     64 bit, 5 years support
      *   kubuntu 18.04: 64 bit as well as 32 bit, 3 years support

motivation:
* ubuntu wants to save money and manpower for 64 bit versions.
  can understan that. 
* 32 bit: we are using old thinkpads since 4 years for kubuntu 
  14.04 and we love it. so we wannt to keep the hardware.

now we have to make a decision. anyway thanks for the help and for 
ubuntu/kubuntu system itself. never again we go back to windows.

further question: if we install kubuntu 18.04 with 3 years
support. do we have 5 years support for the base system 18.04 ?

regards chb

Comment: The repositories of all the Ubuntu flavors are the same, so after 3 years you would still be able to update. But packages maintained by the Kubuntu-team are not going to be updated in the repository and there is no guarantee that you don't run in depency problems.